# Logic behind order of repositories shown for a GitHub user

Tags: github

Is the order of repositories for a user simply the order of entry? I cannot see any logic in what is at the top of, for example, [thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot).

I'm thinking of writing a tool to get my desired ordering using the API, but maybe if I grokked the order better I could scan the list easier and not feel so compelled.

For example, as of 2013-12-21 16:01, these are the top two items on Thoughtbot:

1. shoulda-matchers - Last updated a day ago
2. suspenders - Last updated a day ago

But then the top item does not say it was [updated a day ago](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commits/master) ;

> Dec 18, 2013 - Make `order` option Rails 4.0.1-compatible - aff7bd7e2a - authored 20 days ago

And the second on the list says it [was authored a day ago](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/commits/master)

> Dec 20, 2013 - Add spring - 078237f9ed - authored a day ago

Update; 
The pull request is not related to the dates, see below. The comments are not related either. Thus I conclude perhaps there is evidence of a github bug. I will send another note to them. Perhaps this detail will help!

The two Closed Pull requests as of  2013-12-30Mon.09:19:09
TOP item = 11d ago ; 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pulls?direction=desc&page=1&sort=created&state=closed
Make `order` option Rails 4.0.1-compatible
This is a fix for #388. From the commit: The way that we figure out whether the value which is p…
    by mcmire 11 days ago
    3 comments

2ND ITEM
https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/pulls?direction=desc&page=1&sort=created&state=closed
Add spring
It's good stuff, and Rails 4.1 will include Spring by default. We may as well get on this train e…
    by jferris 10 days ago
    1 comment

Comment: Not about programming, but how the SaaS chooses to display information. Better for GitHub:Support

Comment: @random , I have tried Github support for some issues and not had alot of response. Also, I wish SO were more in the mode of liking questions. Nowadays maybe 30% of the questions I come here from a google are closed as inappropriate. Sigh. I thought this one was ok.

Comment: Sometimes GitHub:Support just are a little overloaded, and with the holidays, times may be a little slower. If you have questions about the amount of questions you've reached via Google being closed, do ask on Meta about it, with links and reasons.

Comment: Thank you @random for your empathetic advice. Github support I mean I contacted like a month or two ago and got an answer on I think one of three questions. Re SO, honestly there are so many disapproved posts that I feel pretty down about the odds of doing any good. There appear to be 'reasons'. Wikipedia is similar, I guess the experienced ones are a little tired of so much work we give you all. I wish there could be a paid option to fix that. If you know a specific thread to which I should comment, I will :).

Comment: To the ordering, look in the date Pull Requests are made against the repo as well. GitHub API issues, pushing/pulling/merging/etc with GitHub would be OK here. Other things, like layout, Markdown and general account issues, if not GitHub:Support, then may be better suited to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/github

Comment: Two items. 1.If this post is better suited to another site, ie webapps, then shouldn't someone just move it? I am not allowed to do that, right? ; 2.Detail added re pull dates.

Comment: You can flag it for moderator attention to move it there given it's not one of the usual sites to move it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're ordered by time of last commit, newest at the top.

Comment: The front page seems to say that is true, but I can't make sense of the commits themselves, see my detail added?

Comment: You are right, @Peter. It is ordered by time of last commit per Github staff. They said that the algorithm considers ALL Branches! That is why the commit date can be obscure. In this case, looking to find something like 2013-12-21  on shouldamatchers branches shows the commit. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/branches Thank you for your answer, I accepted :).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the GitHub API it says that the repositories are ordered by their creation date. [Github API for listing repositories](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories)

It seems that this is also the case if for your personal repositories in the repository view. *(Just tested this on my account)*

*(**EDIT**:  I just realized that for the account that you mentioned, the repos are ordered by their last commit. However this is not the case for my account. It seems that the ordering depends on the overall number of repos linked to the account)*

Comment: thank you for pointing out the API url. I had seen it but I like having it here too.